# How to calculate the difference between the min and max value of time in a series of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following rows in a mysql database:

```
Object1 2012-03-25 13:02:17         
Object2 2012-03-25 13:02:20         
Object3 2012-03-25 13:03:22         
Object1 2012-03-25 13:03:25         
Object4 2012-03-25 13:03:38         
Object1 2012-03-25 13:03:41         
Object5 2012-03-25 13:03:46         
Object4 2012-03-25 13:04:15         
Object6 2012-03-25 13:09:16         
Object1 2012-03-25 13:10:02         
Object4 2012-03-25 13:10:33         
Object3 2012-03-25 13:26:52
```

I want to calculate the time difference between the earliest time of an object and the latest time for the same object.

For example the output value for Object1 would be approximately 8 seconds.

Would I be able to accomplish this with sql?  If so how?  If not, how?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You are able to reference the MAX and MIN in any query like this:

```
SELECT objectid, DATEDIFF(MAX(time),MIN(time)) as diff
FROM objects
GROUP BY objectid
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT obj, MIN(otime) AS mn, MAX(otime) AS mx, DATEDIFF(MAX(otime),MIN(otime)) AS df
FROM mytable
GROUP BY obj
```

should do it.  You don't need tthe mn and mx columns, but I like to see them for checking purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT obj_name, MIN(obj_time) as min_time, MAX(obj_time) as max_time, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(obj_time),MAX(obj_time)) as diff_seconds
FROM table1
GROUP BY obj_name
```